# Laravel Eloquent Pluck without losing the key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following collection in Laravel:

```
 ["TheNumbers":[{"episodeID":16818,"episodeNumber":100,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"episodeID":16818,"episodeNumber":210,"created_at":"2017-02-20 21:30:38","updated_at":"2017-02-20 21:30:38"}]
```

If I run the following code:

```
$TheEpisode->TheNumbers->pluck('episodeNumber');
```

I will get the following result:

```
[100,210]
```

I would like to keep the keys for each number, how can I achieve this?

## EDIT: EXPECTED RESULT:

This is my expected result:

```
[{"episodeNumber":100},{"episodeNumber":210}]
```

## PHILIS PETERS (improved)

```
TheEpisode->TheNumbers->reduce(function ($result, $episode) {
          $episodeData = (collect())->put('episodeNumber', $episode['episodeNumber']);
          $result[] = $episodeData;
          return $result;
        }));
```

Comment: What key do you want to "keep"? Confused.

Comment: @MikeBarwick - episodeNumber key :)

Comment: Then you should be able to just do `...->pluck('episodeID', 'episodeNumber');`

Comment: This will return wrong output

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this, it should work using `map`...

```
return $TheEpisode->TheNumbers->map(function ($episode) {
    return ['episodeNumber' => $episode['episodeNumber']];
});
```

Comment: it worked! However, I have multiple episodeNumber, only 1 is being shown.

Comment: This is the output I am getting from your code: {"episodeNumber":210}

Answer (score 49):

[Pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) can take two params. The second of which is what the value can be keyed by.

You should be able to do:

```
$TheEpisode->TheNumbers->pluck('episodeNumber', 'episodeID');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great, but I need to keep the key.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!!

Comment: Saved me again exactly 2 years later!!! 25 Oct 2020!

Answer (score 9):

This can be simply achieved by passing a second argument to [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck). From the documentation:

> You may also specify how you wish the resulting collection to be
>   keyed:

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('name', 'product_id');

$plucked->all();

// ['prod-100' => 'Desk', 'prod-200' => 'Chair']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$collection->forget(['created_at', 'updated_at]);
```

This will simply left two first key-value pairs. Worth to keep in mind:

> forget does not return a new modified collection; it modifies the collection it is called on.

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-forget)

This should work properly:

```
$collection->only(['episodeID', 'episodeNumber']);
```

Comment: This will work however this is not futureproof (If I will add more columns to my database later, they will be exposed)

Comment: Try this: $collection->only(['episodeID', 'episodeNumber']);

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$TheEpisode->TheNumbers->lists('episodeNumber');
```

the key will remain.

Comment: Method does not exist

Comment: are you sure you put "lists" not "list" ?

Comment: Tried both. (I think in 5.4 lists method does not exist)

Comment: Ow i see, been using it in 5.2 maybe it is not available in 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mapWithKeys` like this:

```
$TheEpisode->TheNumbers->mapWithKeys(function ($theNumber) {
return ['episodeNumber' => $theNumber['episodeNumber']
});
```

I assume you want the result like this:

`"TheNumbers":['episodeNumber':100,'episodeNumber':210]`

Comment: Nope,  this cannot happen because you are repeating episodeName for 2 times.  What I want is like original  idea but only episodeName field.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of updated Laravel, I tried all and I found

`return Model::get(['name','id'])`

will give reduced results with key => value.