# Laravel query builder combine pluck() with keyBy()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I would like Laravel query-builder to return an array of `key => value`.

For example, for `users` table which has columns `username`, `email` return something like:

```
Array
(
    [email1] => username1
    [email2] => username2
)
```

Now, I can achieve each one of the with either `pluck('username')` or with `keyBy('email')`.

I can use php array functions to manipulate result returned by `keyBy` in order to achieve what I want:

```
$tmpRes = DB::table('users')
    ->select(['username', 'email'])
    ->get()->keyBy('email')->toArray();

$res = array_map(function ($el) {
    return $el->username;
}, $tmpRes);
```

I wonder whether there is a direct way to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355330/1033654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluck actually allows a second parameter as a key

```
public static function pluck($column, $key = null)
```

So all you have to do is pass that in

```
$tmpRes = DB::table('users')
    ->pluck('username', 'email')
    ->toArray();
```